# How to run Minecraft from a different folder

Tags: c#, minecraft-modding

My problem is that I can run minecraft from a different folder, but when I run it, it is still using .minecraft folder. It saves the worlds there and so on. How can I run it like "everything get from and save to my folder"?
I heard you can mod it to run from somewhere else, but I did not found it anywhere.

```
        public static string generateSession(string username, string password, int clientVer)
    {
        return httpGET("https://login.minecraft.net?user=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&version=" + clientVer);
    }

    private static string httpGET(string URI)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URI);
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }

    public static void startMinecraft(bool mode, int ramMin, int ramMax, string username, string sessionID, bool debug, int modpack)
    {
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\";
        string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\";
        string mcFolder;
        //Launching a modpack
        if (modpack == 0)
            mcFolder = @".gslauncher\vanilla";
        else mcFolder = @".gslauncher\gstech";
        Process proc = new Process();
        if (debug == true)
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
        else
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "javaw";
        //Online and offline modes
        if (mode == true)
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xms" + ramMin + "m -Xmx" + ramMax + "m -Djava.library.path=" + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/natives -cp " + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/minecraft.jar;" + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/jinput.jar;" + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/lwjgl.jar;" + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/lwjgl_util.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft " + username + " " + sessionID;
        else
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xms" + ramMin + "m -Xmx" + ramMax + "m -Djava.library.path=" + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/natives -cp " + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/minecraft.jar;" + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/jinput.jar;" + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/lwjgl.jar;" + appData + mcFolder + "/bin/lwjgl_util.jar net.minecraft.client.Minecraft " + username;
        proc.Start();
    }
```

Comment: I think this fits better to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @sharethis really? for real? I got redirected to other sites 3 times since 2 hours

Comment: Or maybe http://gaming.stackexchange.com/? This certainly isn't the site for working out how to run existing games, that's for sure.

Comment: I am just modifying (creating something new) for the original game

Comment: The [Minecraft modding forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/140-modification-development/) would be the best place.

Comment: I did not find anything usefull here

Comment: @DragonCz I mean it's the best place to *ask*. They're specialized for that subject.

Answer (score 2):

The [Minecraft modding forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/140-modification-development/) is probably the best place to get answers like this. Searching there is your best bet and you can likely find the answer. I did a search there and found that someone had asked this [question already](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1559556-how-to-change-minecraft-directory-folder/page__hl__+minecraft++from++different++folder). It looks like the best way is to use [Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-100-mods-options-news/). If you want to do it through code, I suggest you ask the question over there.

Comment: I am not looking for a launcher, I am looking to do it via code, and that is why I am tagging it as C# and posting a chunk of the code I used

Comment: In that case, I think it's a bit too specialised for this site, and the forum Byte56 mentioned would be the best bet.